# Resources on operations on finine sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

More than $25$ years ago I came up with this problem. I know the solution empirically, but I want some help to understand it in a better way. Which theories deal with such a problem? Do you recommend any resources?

A researcher had a finite sequence of $n$ numbers, $n \geq 3$. She wanted to make them all equal. She designed a program that takes $\frac{1}{m}(a(i)-ik)$ and adds it to $a(i+1)$. When the program reaches $a(n)$, it gives $\frac{1}{m}(a(n)-nk)$ back to $a(1)$. That makes all numbers in the sequence equal.

$n$, $m$, and $k$ are positive integers.

If we know $n$, $m$, $k$, and the initial $a(n)$, can we find the original sequence?

For example, $n=30$, $m=3$, $k=10$, and the initial $a(30)=135625$.
The program takes $\frac{1}{3}(a0(1)-10)$ and gives it to $a0(2)$, then it takes $\frac{1}{3}(a1(2)-20)$ and gives it to $a0(3)$ and so on. When it reaches $a(30)$, it gives $\frac{1}{3}(n1(30)-300)$ back to $a1(1)$, and that makes all numbers in the sequence equal. 
Does this operation have an established name? Are there any resources I could find to study this operation?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What does $\frac{1}{3}(n1(30)-300)$ mean?

Comment: It means one third of the 30th term (after it got an addition from the a(29)) minus 300